# How to rotate map view smoothly with  bearing in android

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I am trying to rotate map view when the user changes his direction ie if  user takes left and right turns it should rotate accordingly.I am rotating map view basing on current location bearing it is rotating correctly but it was jittering.Here is the code which i used for rotation

```
   public void onGPSUpdate(Location location) 
{
     boolean check=isBetterLocation(location, tempLoc);
    tempLoc=location;

     if(check){
        showLocation(location);

     }

}
isBetterLocation method is copied from google docs for better location.

private void showLocation(Location loc){
   mRotateView.rotate(-loc.getBearing());             
   }
```

I registered a location updates with time interval 0 and min distance of 10 for frequent updates.Here my problem is map view is jittering always,can any one tell me how can I smoothly rotate map view like other applications like waze maps do.Thanks...

Comment: You need to clarify if the problem is the bearings you are getting from the gps jumping around.  Or the actual rotating to a new bearing which is what Konrad is talking about.

Comment: @lfor yes u r correct the bearing which I am getting is jumping around.Do u have any idea on this.

Comment: I know the faster you go the better it will get.  You need some sort of filtering on the values you are getting.

Comment: @lfor yeah do u have any idea which filter should we use here.

Comment: Well I don't do any filtering in my app doing the same sort of thing.  Filtering will just make it slower getting a good direction when starting to move.  If I was to filter I would do a simple new_heading = (old_heading * (1-filter)) + (gps_heading * filter) style and then experiment with the filter value starting with something like 0.25.  This will need some tweaking to cope with the 359-0 discontinuity but some simple adding or subtracting 360 if the difference is > 180 degrees should sort it.

Comment: dharan, from what you wrote in your original post, you want a "map should always point towards north". This means you should use digital compass, not GPS readings. Please, note that you should calibrate your digital compass before its readings become more or less accurate on most of modern devices.

Comment: @Stan sorry by default google maps always points to north my actual requirement is map should rotate according to travel direction,I edited my question.Thanks

Answer (score 4):

are you trying to rotate the map in a smooth way such as by one degree at a time or just have it go from degree A to degree B on location update ?

Something like

```
while (oldAngle != newAngle)
{
mapView.rotate(newAngle);
// this is where you would decied to add or subtract; 
newAngle ++ or -- ; 
}
```

not sure if this would work exactly as the loop would run really quickly so maybe do this as a asynctask and add a pause in there to simulate a smooth rotation.

```
Double angle = Math.atan2((userstartPoint.getX() - userendPoint.getX()), userstartPoint.getY() - userendPoint.getY());
            angle = Math.toDegrees(angle);
            map.setRotationAngle(angle);
```

so basically I get the start point (new location) and then the end point (old location) and do a Math.atan2 on it as you can see. Then convert that to a degree and set it to my map rotation. 
Now it does not do a smooth rotation but I don't need that. Here is where you could set up your own stepper for a smooth rotate. Unless the google maps already has one.

Comment: i have to rotate it if user changes his travel direction ie for example if he takes left turn it should rotate left.

Comment: what you could try to do is get the old map.angle and then get the new heading and run that through a loop that either subtracts or adds to the new heading 1 degree at a time and then set that each time to the map.rotation.

Comment: @Konard Thank you for u r idea, I tried this but its not working correctly because if we are trying to rotate basing on heading if user device points to different heading then its not rotating accurately.

Comment: here is what I use in my app for a map angle rotation, now this is a bit different because I use the Esri API not google but Im sure you can implement this.
!!! added the code to my original post !!!

Comment: @Konard I did not understand what is userStart x and y in u r code.

Comment: userStart is a Point that I get from the Location(GPS) so userStart.x is a lat point that is converted to the Esri referance. Once I have both points I can get the angle between the two and convert that to a direction which rotates my map so whenever there is a location update on the device it sets the map in that heading.

Comment: @Konard I tried u r solution but its not working as expected.

Comment: @konard I got two location objects and converted into geo points.I got x and y and used  u r formula for getting angle between those two.GeoPoint p1=new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), (int) ( location.getLongitude() * 1E6));GeoPoint p2=new GeoPoint((int) (tempLoc.getLatitude() * 1E6), (int) ( tempLoc.getLongitude() * 1E6));and then used mapView.getProjection for getting x and y points.

Comment: did you try using Math.atan2 that should return you a angle which you can then turn into a degree and pass it to your map view to rotate the map that way.

Comment: and what happens when you pass the result into the mapview?

Comment: it was working initially well but after sometime map rotation is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

As the bearing values of the Location are not very exact and tend to jump a little, you should use a filter for the bearing. For example, keep the last 5 bearing-values in an array and use the average of those values as the bearing to rotate the map to. Or use the filter explained in the [SensorEvent docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html) - it's easier to use and can be tweaked better.

This will smoothen out the rotation of the map resp. keep it more stable.

**EDIT:**

A version of the low-pass filter:

```
public static float exponentialSmoothing(float input, float output, float alpha) {
    output = output + alpha * (input - output);
    return output;
}
```

use it like so:

```
final static float ALPHA = 0.33; // values between 0 and 1
float bearing;

// on location/bearing changed:

bearing = exponentialSmoothing(bearing, newBearing, ALPHA);
```

`bearing` would be the value to use to actually rotate the map, `newBearing` would be the bearing you get from every event, and with `ALPHA` you can control how quickly or slowly the rotation acts to a new orientation by weighting how much of the old and the new bearing is taken into account for the result. A small value weighs the old value higher, a high value weighs the new value higher.

I hope that works out better.

Comment: Thanks for u r idea,I tried averaging bearing but rotation is not proper,I also checked whether the average is greater than or equal to 360 and I made it to 360.

Comment: Yeah there are some subtleties here as the bearing jumps around north resp. 0/360 degrees -- try the implementation of the low-pass filter I add to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To change the bearing of your map, use the `Camera` class. You can define a new `CameraPosition` with the new bearing and tell the camera to move with either `GoogleMap.moveCamera` or `GoogleMap.animateCamera` if you want a smooth movement.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this in my app. What I basically did is that I took the last and second last LatLng of my path and calculate bearing by using

```
public static float getRotationAngle(LatLng secondLastLatLng, LatLng lastLatLng)
{
    double x1 = secondLastLatLng.latitude;
    double y1 = secondLastLatLng.longitude;
    double x2 = lastLatLng.latitude;
    double y2 = lastLatLng.longitude;

    float xDiff = (float) (x2 - x1);
    float yDiff = (float) (y2 - y1);

    return (float) (Math.atan2(yDiff, xDiff) * 180.0 / Math.PI);

}
```

Set this angle as bearing to camera position.

Note: Sometimes (rarely) it rotates map to opposite direction. i am looking for it but if anyone got reason do reply.